# NowJS, SocketIO and Pusher.com

Tags: javascript, node.js, nowjs-sockets, pusher

What are pros and cons for NowJS, SocketIO and PusherApp ?

Favorite Client Language: **JS**

Favorite Server Language: **NodeJS**

Answer (score 0):

### Socket.io

Pro:

- Uses your favorite languages.
- Do it yourself solution. Could also be con.

Cons:

- Scaling could be problem. For example users have memory leaks when using websockets. Also does not have proper support(yet) if you want to scale to multiple CPU's/boxes.

### nowjs

nowJS uses socket.io to provide RPC-library.

Pro:

- Simpler to use sometimes I guess.
- Uses your favorite languages.

Cons:

- Some scaling problem as socket.io

### Pusher

Pro:

- Scaling easier.

Cons:

- Costs money when you get big. Maybe to much?